# Python Openpyxl is unable to check from Column 6 onwards

Tags: openpyxl

I want to use Openpyxl to check if cells.value='OK' and the interior color of its corresponding row in another sheet is !='FF9BCCFF'. I used the code appended at the end. It works fine for Column 1 to 5 in

```
R_sht.cell(row = i, column=7).value=='OK'
```

But when I change to column 6 onwards the code doesn't work. It goes to else block although I have rows that meet the criteria of if block.

I even tested by copying and pasting column 5 to column 6. So both columns have SAME contents/format/etc. And the code works on column 5 but fails in column 6.

I am not sure why there is this issue. I tried on 2 different Excel workbooks. Same issue. Code fails for column 6 onwards.

There is no upload function here for me to show a sample workbook.

But hope someone can still help. Thank you

```
for i in range (first_used_row,last_used_row+1):
 
    if R_sht.cell(row = i, column=7).value=='OK' and IN_sht.cell(row = i, column=1).fill.start_color.index!='FF9BCCFF':
        print(str(i) + "Not Blank")
    else:
        cell_color=IN_sht.cell(row = i, column=1).fill.start_color.index
        print(str(i) + "Blank" + str(cell_color))
```

Comment: Add some code to check the cell values in column 7. Check the type and length also. It may help determine the issue.

Comment: The check is also for the fill of the cell. You should check whether this is true.

Comment: Hi, how do I check the type & length? As I said, I said I copied and pasted column 5 to Column 6. So they are the same. But my code works on column 5 but not column 6. Thank you